# Django FileField file does not open correctly

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my django app i create a model with a fiels of type FileField for store some documents:

```
...
device_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
...
```

in my `settings.py` i have:

```
STATIC_URL = 'mqtt_site/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT='mqtt_site/static/media/'
```

whell, when i my django admin Add form i save data everything work good, my documents was saved in the right position, but when i click on link the path is not correct:

[image]

i get 127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/Weekly_Report-2022-01-14_19-07.pdf
thet is wrong, instead of the correct

127.0.0.1:8000/mqtt_site/static/media/uploads/Weekly_Report-2022-01-14_19-07.pdf

Why djangodont' add the /mqtt_site/static/media path as prefix as defined in my settings.py file?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Media and static shouldn’t share the same folder.